# Why import .obj file in blender not working?

Tags: materials, import, vertex-groups, obj

I imported in blender 3.x a free .obj file with multiple materials (on preview photo) from cgtrader but I see only the model. Here the .mtl file:

```
newmtl wire_177088027
  Ns 32
  d 1
  Tr 0
  Tf 1 1 1
  illum 2
  Ka 0.6941 0.3451 0.1059
  Kd 0.6941 0.3451 0.1059
  Ks 0.3500 0.3500 0.3500
```

If I add

```
map_Kd Maps\DR_WoodMat_Diff.jpg
```

then the model gets the material. But only some parts should get it. Do I have to manually create vertexgroups with corresponding slots? How can I check at cgtrader if a .mtl file assigns all materials to different vertexgroups automatically?

Thanks...